# Nginx doesn't execute PHP files but download them

Tags: nginx, php

I know this question had been asked many times. I checked answers but none of them worked for me. I run this command

```
which nginx
```

And I get `/usr/sbin/nginx`

I try to navigate to that folder and I can see the nginx folder but it says `Not a directory`

I navigated to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` but can't access `default` directory or the domain direcroty I want and it keeps saying the same and I can't access them to make any edits. This is the first time I work on nginx server so please I need help here.

Answer (score 1):

Its heavy to help you as there is a lot of information missing in your question. I'm not sure but i think you don't have PHP configured correctly in Nginx (or maybe not installed PHP at all?)

I recommend you to follow a good tutorial on the internet that explains you how you can setup a webserver on linux with Nginx, PHP and maybe MySQL like this one for example:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

If there still things not clear after folowing such a tutorial you can open a new question but please be more concrete. What did you tried to solve your problem? How are your Nginx configurations and so on.

Good luck!